# MySQL connector does not work with GraalVM and Docker

Tags: java, docker, jdbc, mysql-connector, graalvm

I'm trying to do a basic SQL query using JDBC and mysql-connector-java on an image with Graalvm (The cause of the problem).

Apparently everyone who tries to use GraalVM with JDBC/MySQL and Docker will have the same problem every time.

I'm having the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at com.mysql.cj.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:49)
   at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:67)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getImplementingInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:241)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:211)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:280)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:195)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
   at com.me.test.Main.testJDBC(Main.java:73)
   at com.me.test.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load resource bundle due to underlying     exception java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
   at com.mysql.cj.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:60)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages, locale en_US
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1549)
   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:858)
   at com.mysql.cj.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:58)
... 10 more
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:latest

RUN gu install native-image
WORKDIR /tmp/dist
ADD ./app.jar ./app.jar

COPY ./reflect-config.json ./reflect-config.json

RUN native-image -jar ./app.jar --verbose --no-fallback
RUN  microdnf install zip

ADD bootstrap bootstrap

RUN chmod +x bootstrap
RUN chmod +x ./app

RUN zip -j function.zip bootstrap app


ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

Dependencies in my pom file

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.29</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>21.5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally my java code:

```java
public void testJDBC() throws SQLException, IOException {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://foo.blabla.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/database";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "password";
    try(java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)){
        doSomething(conn);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I followed Mark Rotteveel's recommendation, and added a *"resource-config.json"* file with the following:

```
{
  "resources": {
    "includes": [
      {"pattern": "com.mysql.cj.LocalizedErrorMessages.properties"}
    ]
  }
}
```

And in the *"native-image.properties"* file the following

```
Args = -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/tmp/dist/reflect-config.json -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=/tmp/dist/resource-config.json
```

Fixed the current error, but as expected we have a new one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException
   at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:169)
   at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:174)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getImplementingInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:241)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl$Type.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:211)
   at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:280)
   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:195)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
   at com.me.test.Main.testJDBC(Main.java:77)
   at com.me.test.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I configured the following in the file *"reflect-config.json"*

```
[

  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.SingleConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.FailoverDnsSrvConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.LoadBalanceDnsSrvConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.ReplicationDnsSrvConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.XDevApiDnsSrvConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.FailoverConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.LoadBalanceConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.ReplicationConnectionUrl",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },  {
  "name": "com.mysql.cj.conf.url.XDevApiConnectionUrl",
  "allDeclaredFields": true,
  "allDeclaredMethods": true,
  "allDeclaredConstructors": true
},
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.log.Jdk14Logger",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.cj.log.NullLogger",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
        "name": "com.mysql.cj.log.Slf4JLogger",
        "allDeclaredFields": true,
        "allDeclaredMethods": true,
        "allDeclaredConstructors": true
    },
  {
  "name": "com.mysql.cj.log.StandardLogger",
  "allDeclaredFields": true,
  "allDeclaredMethods": true,
  "allDeclaredConstructors": true
},
  {
    "name": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },

  {
    "name":"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name" : "oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.net.ano.Ano",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.net.ano.DataIntegrityService",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.net.ano.EncryptionService",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  },
  {
    "name":"oracle.net.ano.SupervisorService",
    "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }]
  }
]
```

But for some reason there is a connection error (Tested With AWS RDS, and host.docker.internal).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on foo.blabla.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com:3,306.

Make sure that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running on is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also make sure that the server has not been started with the --skip-networking flag.


    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:462)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at com.me.test.Main.testJDBC(Main.java:104)
    at com.me.test.Main.main(Main.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    ... 6 more
```

This error only occurs using *"ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:latest"*, if I use another VM like *"amazoncorretto:18-alpine"* everything works perfect.

Full Source Code: https://github.com/ederbaum/MySQLGraalVM

Any possible solution?

Comment: The error indicates that the resource file `com/mysql/cj/LocalizedErrorMessages.properties` is missing. I have never used Graal, but https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/ mentions _"By default, the native-image tool will not integrate any of the resources which are on the classpath during the generation into the final image. To make calls such as Class.getResource() or Class.getResourceAsStream() (or their corresponding ClassLoader methods) return specific resources (instead of null), you must specify the resources that should be accessible at run time."_

Comment: In other words, you will need to identify all resources needed by your application and its dependencies, and specify them to be included. Also read the section title [_"Resource Bundles in Native Image"_](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/#resource-bundles-in-native-image) as that seems to be specifically relevant to your case.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. Fixed the current error, but as expected we have a new one. I'll put the details right away.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with GraalVM, but from what I see, you are copying an uber/fat jar into the container which contains all the dependencies. Could it be that the mysql-connecter library included in this fat jar(which your build tool downloaded for your current architecture) is one compatible with `amazoncorretto:18-alpine` and not compatible with `ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:latest` ?

Comment: The command `RUN native-image -jar ./app.jar --verbose --no-fallback` transforms the java code to native. In my example on GitHub I changed the docker file to use a `FROM scratch`  image, where the code that "was java", now runs without even needing an OS or VM. I tested several versions of `mysql-connector-java`, all are in the maven repository which in principle works on different platforms.