# springnative running the nativeBuild it throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.PerConnectionLRUFactory"

Tags: spring-boot, mysql-connector, spring-data-jdbc, spring-native

os:centos7

springboot:3.1.1

application.yml：
spring:
datasource:
driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.109:3306/dow2?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
username: root
password: 123456
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
hikari:
minimum-idle: 2
maximum-pool-size: 8
idle-timeout: 30000
max-lifetime: 1800000
connection-timeout: 30000
pool-name: HikariPool
auto-commit: true
data-source-properties:
cachePrepStmts: true
prepStmtCacheSize: 250
prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
useServerPrepStmts: true
useLocalSessionState: true
rewriteBatchedStatements: true
cacheResultSetMetadata: true
cacheServerConfiguration: true
elideSetAutoCommits: true
maintainTimeStats: false

graalvm:Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment GraalVM EE 22.3.2 (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-jvmci-22.3-b15)

maven build: mvn --batch-mode -T4 -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE -Pnative clean native:compile

running the nativeBuild it throws:
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed loading the class 'com.mysql.cj.PerConnectionLRUFactory'.
at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150)
at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:193)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createPreparedStatementCaches(ConnectionImpl.java:1023)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:418)
... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.PerConnectionLRUFactory
at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132)
at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:186)
... 83 common frames omitted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbvSL.png)

I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue that MySql connector doesn't have proper native configuration yet: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1748 also this post seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723781/mysql-connector-does-not-work-with-graalvm-and-docker